# Buildroot: how to modify device tree for custom board?

Tags: linux-kernel, buildroot, device-tree

I'm new to Buildroot system (I used Yocto before). I need to modify the device tree for my board, which is the best way to achieve that?

Thanks a lot,
Simone

Comment: "*I need to modify the device tree for my board ...*" -- Avoid modifying the **.dtsi** files that describe generic hardware, such as the SoC. Since you didn't modify the SoC, there's no reason to modify its **dtsi** file. Make your changes to the **.dts** file (which describes the board), or consolidate your customizations in a new **.dtsi** file that is then *included* at the end of the **.dts** file. This takes advantage of the fact that the DT source is compiled in linear sequence, and you can redefine existing (or add/delete) nodes & properties in later statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a copy of the dts (typically in `board/<company>/<boardname>`). Point to that dts in the "Out of tree custom DTS" menu entry (`BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH`) in the Buildroot menuconfig. Obviously, you need to build a kernel and enable the device tree option for this to work.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, thanks so much! I remember that we managed to compile the kernel externally and then recreate the SD image using external crosscompiled files. However I think your solution is better and simplier if you want to keep the build in one place!